# How to know which servlet will handle a "submit" query from a JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets, request, submit

I'm relatively new to programming web applications with Servlets, JSP, etc..

In my case, I'd like to have 2 servlets and 5 JSPs, one servlet is good to go and is initializing a connection to a MySQL database as well as redirecting to various JSPs and the other Servlet is an ServletAdmin corresponding to a JSPAdmin page, with more privileges concerning the databases access than the other servlet.

Now I'd like for the ServletAdmin to only handle requests from the JSPAdmin page but I don't know how it really works, do I have to parameter my servlet with the @WebServlet annotation? I've already done that for the first one like that :

```
@WebServlet(
       name = "ServletConnection",
       displayName = "Connection handling Servlet",    
       urlPatterns = {"/JSPConnection", "/JSPInit","/JSPCaddie","/JSPPay"}
)
```

I don't really get what I'm doing here, I searched for my question before and came accross that solution so I *tried* to make something out of it, but I'd rather ask to be sure.

Every JSP and every Servlet are currently in the root of their respective folder

My JSPs are named respectively as cited in the urlPatterns and in my paragraph above and so are my Servlets.

Comment: you could probably use different starting URLs, like `@WebServlet("/admin/*")` for the admin stuff and something like `@WebServlet("/user/*")` for the rest and let all request URLs start with either admin or user. (though I have never used the annotation to be honest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever class you give into action field inside the form, that servlet handles the submit request. Value of action and urlpatterns should match. That is how your request would know which servlet will handle your request.

If you are not using form, href value should match with the urlpatterns.

```
<form method="POST" action='UserController' name="frmAddUser">
        User ID : <input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="userid"
            value="<c:out value="${user.userid}" />" /> <br /> 
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <a href="UserController">Click Here </a>
```

Annotation:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", description = "This is a servlet with annotations", urlPatterns = "/UserController")
```

Comment: Oh, ok I think I get it, so the name of the servlet I put in the
    <form action = "NAME"> some HTML code </form> 
will be the one handling the requests of that JSP

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not to complicate too much and not to drown servlet with a lot of diverse logic. If you have a servlet logic that suits more than one jsp, it's ok. Use it. Assign a URL value to that servlet and use it on any page that you like.

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns={"/whatever"})
```

And within your JSP form:

```
<form action="whatever" method="POST">
```

Good luck :)